# How do I make my app run in background on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, background-process

How can I create an iPhone app that runs in the background and receives data from a web service and produces push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS app running in the background, you need to specify it in the info.plist.

required background modes = app plays audio,

web services are possible to use with iOS which one you like REST or SOAP?
For push notification you need external server or service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and i'm using Facebook api. Would you provide any sample tutorial for running in background?

Comment: Basically, there is no need for tutorial 'cause it is very easy. Just specify in your plist which kind of action you wish to use in background (sound,location or VoIP) and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

As apple documentation application will run in background maximum 10 min after that application will not run in background expect audio,GPS like some other